# Python requests find proxy latency

Tags: python, python-requests, ping

I am trying to test the latency of a proxy by pinging a site while using a proxy with a login. I know requests easily supports proxies and was wondering if there was a way to ping/test latency to a site through this. I am open to other methods as well, as long as they support a proxy with a login. Here is an example of my proxy integration with requests

```
import requests

proxy = {'https' : 'https://USER:PASS@IP:PORT'}

requests.get('https://www.google.com/', proxy=proxy)
```

How can I make a program to test the latency of a proxy with a login to a site?

Comment: A "ping" usually refers to an ICMP echo request, it has nothing to do with HTTP. If you just want to do simple HTTP request you should tell us what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I am actually trying to test the latency of the proxy. Let me edit my response to better reflect that.