# How to easily obtain the latency of proxies with only a few lines of code in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, latency

I am making something in one of my scripts that should be able to weed out all of my proxies that are slow. The proxies are stored on each line a file called proxies.txt. I want to be able to specify the maximum latency in milliseconds with a variable. I saw a similar question here [Python requests find proxy latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981419/python-requests-find-proxy-latency) but it was unanswered. If there is a way to do this please let me know.

Comment: What platform are you on? You could use `curl` if you're on Linux/Unix, but  Are these HTTP/HTTPS proxies? Do you currently have a way you're using the proxies in Python? What's stopping you from using [`requests` with a proxy](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) to measure the average ping time to some URL, such as in the answer you linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This wasn't 100% of what you asked for this returns a true or false depending on if the proxy responds in time**

```
def ping(host):

    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower() == 'windows' else '-c'

    command = ['ping', param, '1', '-w', 250, '-n', '1', host]
    return subprocess.call(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) == 0
```

That returns a boolean (true or false) if it responds within 250 milliseconds. I'm sure it it easy enough to modify this to return that to return the correct value. Then all you would need to do is put that in a for loop for each line in the file. also with this you would have to strip the port number and semicolon off of the proxy test it then re-attach it which I did in this code:
**You will have to change this if you want to use this because this is from a project I coded.**

```
def check_proxies(filename):
    filename = str(filename)
    f = open(filename)
    lines = 0
    for _ in f:
        lines = lines + 1
    f.close()

    EstimatedTime = lines * config.Ping_Timeout
    print(f"{bcolors.Blue}Checking proxies... this will take at max {bcolors.OKGREEN}{EstimatedTime / 1000}{bcolors.Blue} seconds{bcolors.ENDC}")

    with open(filename) as f:
        workingProxies = []
        LineNum = 0
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip("\n").strip('\r')
            line = line.split(":")
            line_port = line[1]
            line_ip = line[0]
            if LineNum == 50:
                if config.extras.Proxy_Joke.Proxy_Joke_Extra:
                    Info.print_dad_joke()
                else:
                    pass
            LineNum = LineNum + 1
            if ping(line_ip):
                workingProxies = workingProxies + [f"{line_ip}:{line_port}"]
            else:
                pass
        if len(workingProxies) == 0:
            print("Error, no working proxies were detected, are you connected to the internet?")
    return workingProxies


def get_file_lines():
    InputProxies = 0
    with open(config.Proxy_File) as G:
        for _ in G.readlines():
            InputProxies = InputProxies + 1
    return InputProxies
```

I don't know how I'd go about doing what you want to do but this worked for me in a project I worked on.

Comment: I was able to implement it just fine, but when it tried to execute the command it spammed this kind of stuff:
"ping: 62.75.203.118:3838: Name or service not known
ping: 195.154.237.156:3838: Name or service not known
ping: 79.101.98.2:53281: Name or service not known
ping: 85.25.15.211:3838: Name or service not known
ping: 51.15.149.176:3838: Name or service not known
ping: 46.255.99.7:41258: Name or service not known
ping: 182.253.169.40:8080: Name or service not known
ping: 212.83.157.111:3838: Name or service not known"
 I'm on debian 10 if that helps at all.

Comment: I'd need more context to answer that for sure, but what it sounds like the issue is when you ping each proxy you'd need to strip off the port. Just based off of what you showed me I cannot tell if you did that or not. but in "check_proxies" it grabs the full proxy (example: 12.34.567.890:1234) and splits it at the colon which gives you ["12.34.567.890", "1234" then uses the ping function to ping "line[0]" if that returns true then the working proxy is ```line[0] + ":" + line[1]``` which would be (12.34.567.890:1234) I use windows but I'm pretty sure you cant ping an IP with a port on Debian.

Comment: @Supergamer5465 Also if that didn't make much sense it is because I've been up for an hour just reply to this if you need any more help and I won't be asleep.